# Inserir múltiplos registros php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

Estou desenvolvendo um site de autos e quando o usuário  fazer o cadastro do veículo ele tem a opção de inserir várias imagens do veículo. Eu tenho o código de upload, mas queria saber como inserir mais de uma imagem no campo de imagens da tabala (Exemplo Banco Dados: imagem_veiculo : 01.jpg, 02.jpg,...) ou não sei se é melhor fazer a inserção de múltiplas linhas em uma tabela específica.
Se alguém puder dar exemplos.

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

    //INFO IMAGEM
    $file       = $_FILES['img'];
    $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    //PASTA
    $folder     = 'upload';

    //REQUISITOS
    $permite    = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
    $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 10;

    //MENSAGENS
    $msg        = array();
    $errorMsg   = array(
        1 => 'O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido na diretiva upload_max_filesize do php.ini.',
        2 => 'O arquivo excede o limite definido em MAX_FILE_SIZE no formulário HTML.',
        3 => 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente.',
        4 => 'Nenhum arquivo foi enviado.',
        6 => 'Pasta temporária ausênte.',
        7 => 'Falha em escrever o arquivo em disco.',
        8 => 'Uma extensão do PHP interrompeu o upload do arquivo.'
    );

    if($numFile <= 0)
        echo 'Selecione uma imagem!';
    else{
        for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
            $name   = $file['name'][$i];
            $type   = $file['type'][$i];
            $size   = $file['size'][$i];
            $error  = $file['error'][$i];
            $tmp    = $file['tmp_name'][$i];        

            $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
            $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

            if($error != 0)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name : </b>".$errorMsg[$error];
            else if(!in_array($type, $permite))
                $msg[] = "<b>$name : </b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
            else if($size > $maxSize)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name : </b> Imagem ultrapassa limite de 10MB";
            else{

                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder."/".$novoNome))
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name : </b> Upload realizado com sucesso!";
                else{
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name : </b> Desculpe ocorreu um erro!";
                }

            }

        }


        $insert = "INSERT INTO upload 
                    (imagens)
                    VALUES 
                    ('{$novoNome}')";
        $exe_insert = mysql_query($insert, $con);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto é você ter uma tabela de imagens, e colocar uma linha para cada imagem.
Nessa tabela você tem que ter o `id` que referencia o registro do veículo:

Exemplo:

Tabela de Veículos:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`veiculos`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `marca` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
  `modelo` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '',
  `ano` YEAR,
  `datacadastro` DATETIME,
  `datamodificacao` DATETIME,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Tabela de Imagens

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`imagens`(
  `id_veiculo` INT DEFAULT 0,
  `imagem` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT ''
);
```

Já o `INSERT` você pode fazer em uma única `query`, por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO imagens (id_veiculo, imagem) VALUES
(1, 'imagem1.jpg'),
(1, 'imagem2.jpg'),
(1, 'imagem3.jpg');
```

Comment: Achei bem bacana sua ideia Roberto, mas o problema que tenho é que ele está salvando no banco apenas o nome da última imagem selecionada, mas na pasta de destino ele envia todas as imagens. Tem ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Isso acontece porque o seu `INSERT` esta fora do `FOR`, por esse motivo ele salva somente a ultima

Comment: Genial cara, funcionou direitinho muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Ou também como amigo acima disse colocando:

```
create table images(
id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
id_veiculos int unsigned default null,
imagem blob not null,
primary key (id),
constraint fk_veiculos_id foreign key (id_veiculos) references veiculos(id)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Ola meu amigo veja estes link's: 
http://blog.wieczorek.com.br/index.php/como-fazer-o-upload-de-arquivos-para-um-banco-de-dados-mysql-utilizando-o-php?blog=1

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.multiple.php

https://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/161933-mega-tutorial-upload-simples-e-multiplo/

Comment: Essa não é a dúvida dele. A dúvida dele é como ficaria armazenado no banco de dados o caminho da imagem.